# Generating fake number for a 25 digit PII number in a file containing millions of rows

Tags: python, big-data, privacy

I have to expose some sensitive data containing a PII column that has a 25 digit number. Rest of the columns aren't PII data. This is done such that the data can be safely shared to the larger audience without the original PII column's data. but if required I need to check the original value, hence a look up file is needed which maps the PII with its pseudo number.

How do I generate a pseudo unique number such that we can later map back to original data if required ?

Currently there are about 22 million rows.  There could be at max 50 million such rows of data later on as the data keeps coming in.

I was thinking of the UUIDs but they aren't really human friendly & UUIDs would be bad at indexing later on if we move to a database (Over thinking much?). Also joining two dataframes based on indexing could be slow I reckon.

My current thought process using pandas (for the first file containing 22 million rows)

1. shuffle the lines with pandas (assuming it fits in memory)
2. add a column with a auto incrementing field (say Psuedo_number)
3. add another column with uuids (UUID4)
4. Create a lookup file with our new pseudo_number, UUID, original PII number

now when new PII data comes in

1. read the highest value of the pseudo_number from the lookup file
2. use that (+1) as the starting number for the above process on the new data

**tldr** I need to generate unique random numbers for PII column in a file containing 22 millions rows & maintaining a look up file. Later would need to import into a database once system grows.

some intial code:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->

# dummy list
>>> l = [('C0000005', 'RB', 'C0036775', '')] * 27000000
# create a sample dataframe to represents our data of 22+ million rows
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=list('abcd'))
# let the following 'sensitive_col' column represent our 25 digit number for now
>>> df['sensitive_col'] = df.index + 123456789

>>> df.head()


a          b             c        d         sensitive_col
0   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     123456789
1   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     123456790
2   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     123456791
3   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     123456792
4   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     123456793


#actual code!!
# shuffle the rows
>>> df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df['New_ID'] =  df.index + 123 
# create the UUIDs
>>> df['uuid'] = [uuid.uuid4() for _ in range(len(df.index))]

>>> df.head()

           a    b         c       d     sensitive_col   New_ID  uuid
0   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     132571068   123     8c1974cf-49ff-4b87-bfac-b791156d1b1b
1   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     130859684   124     2a170f08-43a9-4a1d-acf5-b537a229c7e9
2   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     135318849   125     5b265c8e-35ea-4100-bac0-c77f4d3f85ea
3   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     145963082   126     77e2e78c-c72a-4738-907a-9e4851a328d2
4   C0000005    RB  C0036775    D185368     141664707   127     de73b056-6c5e-4276-8b93-db44cd9990ba
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you want a "random at a glance" number but it needs to be deterministic then LFSR is what you need

Comment: Random and unique is what I want. Also when we process another million rows it shouldn't have any previous random numbers used, that's why I thought to use this approach.

Comment: You could encrypt the numbers and keep the key secret. That way, the data is worthless without the key, and the guy with the key does not need a lookup file. On the other hand, you cannot just hash the numbers as that would make it possible to reverse the process by matching the hashes with the hashed numbers from another source.

Comment: Yes I agree hashing isn't the right approach. But neither is encrypting and sharing it. What we need is a PRN which can represent the PII. And sharing that instead of the the orginal number. UUID serves the purpose though.

Comment: Your lookup file serves the same function as a cryptographic key. The only difference is, that the cryptographic key would be much smaller, and that useful, secure, cryptographic primitives exist to use it. The lookup file with PRN-generated numbers is only ever as secure as the PRN. I'd much rather use tried-and-proven cryptographics than homebrew PRN which can easily blow up in my face when I screw it up.

Comment: Rather than using homebrew PRN, UUID4 would suffice right? Also even with the cryptographic key we would still need to maintain the key and the lookup file - for easy look back (or you have to decrypt on the fly when needed).Also with if the input isn't unique then the cryptographic output wouldn't also be unique. I am thinking of ignoring the auto increment number and just using UUID4. what are your thoughts on the same?